# python delete \t and \n in intems into a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like:

```
['\t2,6078 NM , 60,0182 T\n', '\t2,6073 NM , 60,0112 T\n', '\t2,6064 NM , 179,9998 T\n', '\t2,6078        NM , 299,9813 T\n', '\t2,6073 NM , 299,9883 T\n', '\t2,6067 NM , 60,0042 T\n', '\t2,6064 NM , 179,9998 T\n', '\n']
```

it comes from a text file, using `readlines()`.

How can I delete the `\t` and `\n` in every item of the list?

I tried using a loop including strap methods of strings but it doesn't work.

the file is:
the original text is:
    Number of Legs: 7
    SRU Track Vertices: 
     37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 13.02 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 11.77 W
     37 3.99 N,  1 11.77 W
     37 3.99 N,  1 10.51 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 10.51 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 9.26 W
     37 3.99 N,  1 9.26 W
     37 3.99 N,  1 8.01 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 8.01 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 6.76 W
     37 3.99 N,  1 6.76 W
     37 3.99 N,  1 5.51 W
     37 14.97 N,  1 5.51 W

```
Distance, Bearing: 
10,9847 NM , 359,9999 T
0,9971 NM , 89,9998 T
10,9847 NM , 179,9999 T
0,9995 NM , 89,9999 T
10,9847 NM , 359,9999 T
0,9971 NM , 89,9998 T
10,9847 NM , 179,9999 T
0,9995 NM , 89,9999 T
10,9847 NM , 359,9999 T
0,9971 NM , 89,9998 T
10,9847 NM , 179,9999 T
0,9995 NM , 89,9999 T
10,9847 NM , 359,9999 T
```

Comment: Better show oryginal text file - maybe it can be done during reading file.

Comment: *What* did you try, and precisely *how* didn't it work?

Comment: not `strap method`  but function `strip()`

Comment: It looks like some CSV file - maybe it will better to use module `csv` which read all file and split to rows and columns.

Comment: the original text is:

Answer (score 1):

`item.strip()` works just fine:

```
>>> a = ['\t2,6078 NM', '60,0182 T\n', '\t2,6073 NM' , '60,0112 T\n', '\t2,6064 NM' ,     '179,9998 T\n', '\t2,6078 NM' , '299,9813 T\n', '\t2,6073 NM' , '299,9883 T\n', '\t2,6067 NM' , '60,0042 T\n', '\t2,6064 NM' , '179,9998 T\n', '\n']
>>> [i.strip() for i in a]
['2,6078 NM', '60,0182 T', '2,6073 NM', '60,0112 T', '2,6064 NM', '179,9998 T', '2,6078 NM', '299,9813 T', '2,6073 NM', '299,9883 T', '2,6067 NM', '60,0042 T', '2,6064 NM', '179,9998 T', '']
```

And you can use it with [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out empty ones:

```
>>> list(filter( bool, [i.strip() for i in a]))
['2,6078 NM', '60,0182 T', '2,6073 NM', '60,0112 T', '2,6064 NM', '179,9998 T', '2,6078 NM', '299,9813 T', '2,6073 NM', '299,9883 T', '2,6067 NM', '60,0042 T', '2,6064 NM', '179,9998 T']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `replace()` function:

```
for element in list:
    x = element.replace('\t','')
    x = x.replace('\n','')
```

This will be better than `strip()` in cases where `\t` is in between.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion may be in what `strip` does, rather than loops. (This is why you should say what you've tried, so we can better understand what the confusion is.)

Strings are immutable (i.e. can't change) so using `.strip()` returns the changed string rather than modifying the original string.

(Also, try using list comprehension to generate a new list, rather than a for-loop to modify the existing one.)

Answer (score 0):

As @furas said, this look like a [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

But, Lets assume you have text file, data.txt, you want to read:

e.g:

> 2,6078 NM , 60,0182 T,  2,6073 NM , 60,0112 T,  2,6064 NM , 179,9998
>   T,    2,6078        NM , 299,9813 T,  2,6073 NM , 299,9883 T,     2,6067 NM
>   , 60,0042 T,  2,6064 NM , 179,9998 T

You can do:

```
data = []
with open("data.txt", "rb") as data_file:
    for lines in data_file:
        data.append(lines.strip().split("\t")) # or whatever your separator is
```